# Attempted to load class "Doctrine_Core"

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to follow these steps:
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/en/manual/hierarchical-data.html

Please, correct me if I am wrong. Firstly, I've created this class in AppBundle/Model route:

```
namespace AppBundle\Model;


class Item extends Doctrine_Record
{
    public function setTableDefinition()
    {
        $this->hasColumn('name', 'string', 255);
    }

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->actAs('NestedSet');
    }
}
```

And then I use it in a controller like this:

```
$treeObject = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Category')->getTree();
```

I have two questions:
- Where do I have to define the Category table and how
- With this previous code I ran into this error: Attempted to load class "Doctrine_Core" from namespace "AppBundle\Controller\Admin

Any idea please? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doctrine has it's bundle for Symfony, that allows to store all config data in YML. https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/index.html - it has "Tree extension" and it is exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: I copied the Category example and now it throws the validation message... "Column 'lft' cannot be null". Do u know where is it wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Classes `Doctrine_Record` and `Doctrine_Core` are part of `Doctrine` in `1.x` version, `Symfony2` is using `Doctrine 2.x` which is completely different than `1.x` version. For example `Doctrine 2.x` does not use [Active Record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern) approach and this is what you are trying to use. In `Doctrine 2` Model classes (Entities) don't extend any class

Check this piece of [doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#creating-an-entity-class) how to use Doctrine2 in Symfony2

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I followed these steps:

1. Install this: http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/index.html
2. Don't forget to set up the configuration for the extensions, in this case for `tree` like this in `config.yml`:

   ```
   stof_doctrine_extensions:
     orm:
       default:
          tree: true
   ```